# Custom needleless gaugeview

Tags: android, android-custom-view, gauge

I am trying to make a custom gauge in android. I googled a lot but I can only find examples for gauges using a needle. I however want to make a range gauge (no needle)

[image: example of what I want]

Can anyone help me or give me an example?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom implementation of `ProgressBar` also exist. Please see https://github.com/Todd-Davies/ProgressWheel.

Hope this helps.